# How to call the Mainactivity method in Asynctask for background work?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, background

I want a method (present in MainActivity) to call from the `doInBackground(File... file)` method of MyAsynctask class (present in MainActivity) and that method have to work in background also because it is time taking and my app stops working for a moment and there is no any dialog appearing which I have called in `onPreExecute()` method how to solve the problem here is my code it is working very fine but taking too much time and my app looks hanged but it is not actually.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getPlayList(File rootFolder) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles();
         //here you will get NPE if directory doesn't contains  any file,handle it like this.
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory() && !file.isHidden()) {
                    if (true) {
                        fileList.addAll(getPlayList(file));
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();
                    song.put("file_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    song.put("file_name", file.getName());
                    fileList.add(song);
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And Asynctask class is below..

```
private class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<File, String, ArrayList> {


    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(File... file) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> songList=getPlayList(folder);
        if(songList!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<songList.size();i++){
                final String fileName=songList.get(i).get("file_name");
                final String filePath=songList.get(i).get("file_path");

            //saving filePath and filName in SQLite Database..
                saveFileToDatabase(filePath, fileName);

            }
        }
        return songList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        p = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        p.setMessage("Please wait...Loading..");
        p.setIndeterminate(false);
        p.setCancelable(false);
        p.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
        if (mFiles != null)
        {
            p.dismiss();
        }
        else
        {
            p.show();
        }
    }
}
```

How to do the work efficiently?

### Solution

And the problem was these lines of code given below:

```
AsyncTaskExample taskExample = new AsyncTaskExample();
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
      //I was writing this below line..
        taskExample.doInBackground(folder);

      //but it should be like in line below..
      taskExample.execute(folder);
```

Comment: If you can replace the AsyncTask for another option (observable, coroutine), that would be the wisest choice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to define a callback, and pass it through in your asynctask's constructor so you can notify your main activity to show the dialog whenever it's needed.

Callback

```
public interface AsyncTaskExampleCallback {
    public void onShowDialog();
    public void onHideDialog();
}
```

Async task

```
class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<File, String, ArrayList> {

    @Nullable
    private AsyncTaskExampleCallback callback = null;

    public AsyncTaskExample(@NotNull AsyncTaskExampleCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(File... file) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList = getPlayList(folder);
        if (songList != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++) {
                final String fileName = songList.get(i).get("file_name");
                final String filePath = songList.get(i).get("file_path");

                //saving filePath and filName in SQLite Database..
                saveFileToDatabase(filePath, fileName);

            }
        }
        return songList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onShowDialog();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
        if (mFiles != null) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onHideDialog();
            }
        } else {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncTaskExampleCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new AsyncTaskExample(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowDialog() {
        //Show dialog here
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideDialog() {
        //Hide dialog here
    }
}
```

Comment: As I posted the question i got my result myself after just 5 minutes by changing some code :D BTW Very very thank you to post your opinion..

Comment: @MdAman can you edit your post with the final result? I'm just curious. I'll edit my post with an exact example soon.

Comment: @MdAman I edited my post. This is an elegant way to do it. Of course there are some lifecycle to handle, but that won't cause problem for sure.